# nodeJS Session : how to set the attribute "sameSite" to "none" only for some routes

Tags: node.js, express-session, samesite

I searched a long time to set the sameSite attribut to none only for some routes without success. (sameSite: 'none', secure: true)
I found a way, not available now, with the middleware express.session. I read the documentation on GitHub but I didn't find a way to customize the session :(

Is it somebody able to provide me with some informations ...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to add more context. What problem are you trying to solve? 'sameSite' is a cookie attribute. Are you trying to modify the express-session cookie based on a specific route or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I read that it's not a good practice to keep this attribute set to none when it's not needed. I'm working whith vue.js to build an App, and I'm using a specific URL to dialog with my server. I need to set to "none" only for  the path : req.hostname.startsWidth('app.')

Comment: I need to set to "none" for the session cookie (connect.sid) only for  the path : req.hostname.startsWidth('app.')

Answer (score 2):

Finally found :)

```
const cookieMaxAge = moment().endOf('days').diff(moment());
const sessionWeb = {store: ... cookie: { maxAge: cookieMaxAge }};
const sessionApp = {...sessionWeb, cookie: { sameSite: 'none', secure: true, maxAge: cookieMaxAge }};
app.use((req, res, next) => (session(req.hostname.startsWith('app') ? sessionApp : sessionWeb))(req, res, next))
```

Comment: It's seem to be not the good solution, since I added this code, I have some errors  like MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. If I undestand correctly a new midleware is created for each connection :(

Comment: Finally :app.use(session(sessionWeb));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.hostname.startsWith('app')) {
    req.session.cookie.sameSite = "none"
    req.session.cookie.secure = true
  }
  next()
})